# Any PuTTY frontend to not see that GUI anymore?

Tags: user-interface, putty

I am bound to use PuTTY because of various processes and scripts, but that GUI is really getting on me. So if I cannot use another SSH tool, can I have something on top of PuTTY to make the experience minimally bearable? I'm only aware of MTPuTTY but the only thing this does is making more tabs of the same cavemen GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of forks and extensions/modifications available, many of them are listed on the PuTTY website ([https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/links.html](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/links.html)). I can name a couple:

- SuperPutty - Possibly something that fits your request, it allows tabbed sessions and has a somewhat different user interface.
- KiTTY - This doesn't overhaul the interface very much but there are some features not present in the official version.
- ExtraPuTTY - Lots of enhancements, such as LUA scripting.

Comment: Thank you, a valuable list to bookmark. Most of them are forks and rewrites while I was looking for pure frontends because I don't want to mess with compatibility (protocol implementations, whatnot) so I'll try my luck with WinSCP, maybe it's enough for my goal.